# Get value of input field in table row on button click in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm rendering a table over an array of products and each row has a button with a click event to pass the product of that row. That works.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to pass on that same button click the value of an input field of that row:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var product in products)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@product.Day</td>
            <td>@product.Name</td>
            <td>@product.Price</td>
            <td>
                <img src="images/@(product.Name).jpg" alt="" style="width:100px;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="amount" />
            </td>
            <td><button @onclick="(() => Add(product))" >Add</button></td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

In code behind I have the following method (works for when only putting in the product):

```
protected async Task Add(Product product)
{

}
```

How can I change the input field (or replace it with an InputText in an editform for every row?) and have it passed to the Add method like

```
protected async Task Add(Product product, int amount)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried a different approach and added an Amount property to the `Product` class:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public DayOfWeek Day { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

and in my page I made it work like:

```
@foreach (var product in products)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@product.Day</td>
        <td>@product.Name</td>
        <td>@product.Price</td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/@(product.Name).jpg" alt="" style="width:100px;" />
        </td>
        <td>            
            <input type="text" @bind-value="@product.Amount" />
        </td>
        <td><button @onclick="(() => Add(product))" >Add</button></td>
    </tr>
}
```

and in my function I get the value of the input field and set it later on back to 0 after I processed the amount:

```
protected async Task Add(Product product)
{
    // do something useful with the amount and set it back to 0
    product.Amount = 0;
}
```

Still, if there's another solution with passing it as a parameter I'd like to know.

Comment: Yes, there are... I was just going to post something identical to your solution. I'm of the opinion that that is the right way to do it...to add a new field. Elegance in simplicity. Why do you set product.Amount  to 0 , though ?

Comment: As otherwise the amount stays on the number one has put into the corresponding input field. Actually instead of Amount Quantity would've been a better naming for its purpose.

Comment: Maybe, another way would be to extract the row as a single component and use the input field as ```ElementReference``` (@ref keyword).
If you don't want to have the Add Method inside the child component, you can pass an Action or Func as a parameter to the child component.

Answer (score 0):

Just bind the value of your input to a field or property. Then you can use it in your method:

```
<input type="text" id="amount" @bind-value="@_amount" />

@code {
    private int _amount = 0;
    
    protected async Task Add(Product product)
    {
        if (_amount > 0)
                ...
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately that changes the input of every row after the Add method's called to what's in _amount. I could set it back to 0 of course but I thought there would a more elegant way to do this like passing it in as a parameter in the button's onclick.

Answer (score 0):

Below code(took code from pervious post) is working for me.
<InputFile OnChange="@((InputFileChangeEventArgs args) => LoadFilesfunction(args, "rowid"))" />